# Struts2 URL unreachable

Tags: java, struts2, actionresult, xml-configuration, struts2-namespace

I'm really racking my head here with Struts2 - I'm able to access the JSP pages by omitting part of the path.  Note the path suppose to include `pages/welcome_user.jsp`.  The key is to look at the word `pages` in the path.

here's the `struts.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="default" namespace="/User" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Login">
            <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Welcome" class="com.mkyong.user.action.WelcomeUserAction">
            <result name="SUCCESS">pages/welcome_user.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

I'm able to access `login.jsp` via: `http://localhost/Struts2Example/User/Login`
and `welcome_user.jsp` via: `http://localhost/Struts2Example/User/Welcome`
Note that in both URL, I'm able to drop `pages`, why?

source: 
http://www.mkyong.com/misc/how-to-use-mkyong-tutorial/

Can someone go through the above tutorial and tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. You should access pages through actions, not directly.

Comment: You're not "accessing JSP pages", you're accessing actions, that happen to use JSPs as their results. It's the same way you can access a servlet that forwards to a JSP, or streams a file back from the file system--from the client's perspective it's just a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have used URLs that are mapped to the actions in the `struts.xml`.

The action method is executed and returns a result code `SUCCESS`. This result you can find in the action config. Then result is executed, if the type of result isn't set the default is `dispatcher`, and request is forwarded to the location specified in the result config.

If location is relative the final absolute location will be determined by the namespace of the package used for this action.

More detailed information of usage namespaces and explanation you can find in the [Struts 2 Namespace configuration](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/namespace-configuration).

You can't drop pages if you are using `dispatcher` result that forwards to JSP. In this case the URL has been rewritten and you can't see the final URL.

Comment: The only thing that helped me to figure out my problem was by me going through the link provided by Roman C.: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation/  Extremely helpful and now I understand it.  Thank you.